# NDK GCC : Could not determine GCC version

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, gcc, android-ndk

I'm trying to execute an Android sample that uses JNI to call C code from a Android Java Activity.

( Hello-jni) using Android Studio in ubuntu 15.04

I get the following error while building my project :

```
      Error:Execution failed for task ':app:
      compileHello-jniArm64- v8aDebugAllSharedLibraryHello-jniMainC'.

      > No tool chain is available to build for platform 'arm64-v8a':
      - Tool chain 'ndk-gcc' (GNU GCC): Could not determine GCC version: 
       failed to execute aarch64-linux-android-gcc -dM -E -.
```

Answer (score 0):

Running gradle with the --info flag to determine the command being run:

```
gradlew :app:compileHello-jniArm64- v8aDebugAllSharedLibraryHello-jniMainC --info
```

In the output you should see a command containing `aarch64-linux-android-gcc -dM -E -` with a full path. Check that you do actually have this binary at the path shown (it should have been included in the android ndk).

Assuming you do, try running the command yourself. It will read from stdin and print a bunch of constants to stdout (gradle is trying to parse the version from this), but you want to see stderr:

```
echo '' | ./aarch64-linux-android-gcc -dM -E - 1>/dev/null
```

If the command fails, an error should be shown which can hint at the problem. In my case it was trying to include a folder `4.9.x` but I had a folder named `4.9`. Most likely there will be a different problem with your setup.